# curve modifier : deviation between curve en model

Tags: curve-modifier

both parts in the same origin / ther is a deviation between model en curve?[image]
I tried to turn the model ,also in edit mode and this is the best result.

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/